# Emulator of specific device

Tags: android, emulation

I receive reports about incorrect work of my app on some devices (ZTE tabs). How can I check and debug it without owning specific model of phone? I heard there are emulators which emulate a particular device. Do you know some?

Comment: How do you know on which platform the bug appear ?

Comment: I'm using [ACRA](http://code.google.com/p/acra/)

Comment: and the report from crash it can send is not enough ?

Comment: Sometimes it doesn't give enough information.

Comment: I have never heard of an emulator for a specific device. I think some manufacturer provide a web emulator, I saw that once but can't remember which. Maybe you could contact the vendor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, I don't believe there are device specific emulators.  You're best bets would be to get you hands on the specific devices, or use a service like Device Anywhere:

http://www.deviceanywhere.com